# How to test swift nested function?

Tags: ios, swift

How do you write test for swift nested function?

Since the function is inside another function, I don't know how to call it from outside.

I'm using nested function because I can't call a private self function in init

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't test nested function, just like you shouldn't test private methods, from [Bad Testing Practices](https://www.objc.io/issues/15-testing/bad-testing-practices/):

> Private means private. Period. If you feel the need to test a private method, there is something conceptually wrong with that method. Usually it is doing too much to be a private method, which in turn violates the Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 3):

Continuing the point from Code Different, from a testing point of view, the following code is identical:

```
// Without nesting
func f() {
    // Do things
    // Do other things we want to test
    // Do more things
}

// With nesting
func fnest() {
    func nest() {
        // Do other things we want to test
    }

    // Do things
    nest()
    // Do more things
}
```

Whatever technique you'd use to test "Do other things we want to test" in `f()` is precisely the same technique that you'd use to test it in `fnest()`. If the piece you want to test is insufficiently accessible, in either case you must redesign (or change your testing goal), but there's nothing special about nested functions.

> I'm using nested function because I can't call a private self function in init

If this is the entire problem, then make the function static and pure. Rather than passing `self`, pass the data required to perform the calculation, and return the result. Then modify `self` inside of `init` rather than in the function.